# Check if the last values were zero except it was a weekend

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to filter the rows in which the last date (see the column-header e.g. `2023-08-11`) has the value 0.0 three times.
The special feature is that a weekend (Saturday or Sunday) should not be taken into account.

```py
data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'holder': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
    'state': ['Test', 'Test', 'Test'],
    '2023-08-06': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    '2023-08-07': [5.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    '2023-08-08': [0.0, 3.0, 6.0],
    '2023-08-09': [0.0, 5.0, 0.0],
    '2023-08-10': [0.0, 5.0, 0.0],
    '2023-08-11': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    '2023-08-12': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    '2023-08-13': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

```py
# (Couting starts from 2023-08-11), because 22 and 13 were a weekend
   ID holder state  2023-08-06  2023-08-07  2023-08-08  2023-08-09  2023-08-10  2023-08-11  2023-08-12  2023-08-13  
0   1    Max  Test         0.0         5.0         0.0         0.0      0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
1   2    Max  Test         0.0         0.0         3.0         5.0      5.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
2   3    Max  Test         0.0         0.0         6.0         0.0      0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

What I want
Only the IDs with the numbers 1 and 3 should be displayed.

```py
   ID holder state  2023-08-06  2023-08-07  2023-08-08  2023-08-09  2023-08-10  2023-08-11  2023-08-12  2023-08-13  
0   1    Max  Test         0.0         5.0         0.0         0.0      0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
1   3    Max  Test         0.0         0.0         6.0         0.0      0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

---

My first solution was this, but the problem is that it is not checking if it is a weekend or not.

```py
filtered_rows = pivot_table[pivot_table.iloc[:, -3:].eq(0.0).all(axis=1)]
```

What I tried

```py
def is_weekend(date):
    print(date)
    return date.weekday() >= 5 

filtered_rows = df[df.iloc[:, -3:].eq(0.0).all(axis=1) & ~df.iloc[:, -1].apply(is_weekend)]

print(filtered_rows)

[OUT] AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to filter in 2 steps? Having evertyhing in one line makes it unreadable.

Comment: Also you didn't post the full output. `print(date)` shows `0.0` which I assume means you're not actually grabbing the date but one of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`dayofweek`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html) to get the weekdays, then slice, aggregate with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# get relevant columns
tmp = df.drop(columns=['ID', 'holder', 'state'])

# get last 3 non-weekend columns, check if all 0
out = df[tmp[tmp.columns[pd.to_datetime(tmp.columns).dayofweek<5][-3:]
            ].eq(0).all(axis=1)]
```

*NB. this assumes the dates are initially sorted.*

Variant:

```
out = df[df[df.columns[pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce').dayofweek<5]
            [-3:]].eq(0).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   ID holder state  2023-08-06  2023-08-07  2023-08-08  2023-08-09  \
0   1    Max  Test         0.0         5.0         0.0         0.0   
2   3    Max  Test         0.0         0.0         6.0         0.0   

   2023-08-10  2023-08-11  2023-08-12  2023-08-13  
0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0  
2         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
```